# "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter" - when trying to test OOP Inheritance

Tags: c#

I'm just trying to understand how Inheritance works in C#. (even though I think I got it, I want to try to do something practical in order to understand)

So I've been trying to create a class with a property and a constructor and another one which inherits this one. But I get an error and I don't really seem to get why.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Test
    {
        public int testing { get; }
        public Test(int p)
        {
            this.testing = p;
        }
    }
    public class Test2 : Test {

    }
}
```

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'p' of 'Test.Test(int)' for line 15
```

Can someone help me understand what's happening and why do I get that error? Thanks.

Comment: When are getting this error? Are you trying to create an instance of Test2

Comment: @PrateekKumarDalbehera: Nope, just this code will create an error due to the implicit constructor for `Test2`.

Comment: Thanks @jonskeet, yes you are absolutely correct - the God of C# 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: Constructors aren't inherited.

Longer explanation: Your `Test2` class *implicitly* has a constructor like this:

```cs
public Test2() : base()
{
}
```

... because you haven't declared any constructors in `Test2`. If you declare *any* constructor in `Test2`, the compiler won't try to provide the implicit one. (Your constructor will need to call `base(...)` providing a value for `p` though.

So you probably want:

```cs
public class Test2 : Test
{
    public Test2(int p) : base(p)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 2 questions, if you don't mind, because those are pretty silly questions (I'm really a noob): why do I need a constructor (can't the class just exist? is it mandatory to have a constructor?) and how does base() work (what's its role?)?

Comment: @JohnSmith: Yes, there has to have a constructor unless it's a static class (in which case it can't inherit from anything). There's no point in inheriting if you can't create an instance. As for the purpose of `base` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base. (It's really not something that can be explained in a comment.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your effort. I will accept your answer asap.

Comment: Hey I'm still looking into this example and I can't really understand what's happening. What is base(p) calling? I've been looking on that page but I can't still figure it out. is base(p) calling the constructor of Test?

Comment: @JohnSmith: It's chaining to the constructor in the base class. It's the second bullet at the top: "Specify which base-class constructor should be called when creating instances of the derived class."